# Error:"SWAP_CALL_FAILED" while using fillQuote function in 0x

Tags: 0x

Hi I am trying to swap tokens using 0x. I try to use fillQuote funtion for swapping from fill the input from API of 0x but I am getting  Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'SWAP_CALL_FAILED'
can anyone help me in resolving this error?

[image]

I am using this API to fill the input in this function https://api.0x.org/swap/v1/quote?buyToken=WETH&sellToken=DAI&sellAmount=100000000000000000